# Force vector layer to render as raster

Tags: python, pyqgis

I want to check `Force layer to render as raster` using pyqgis:

[image]

I have tried:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.renderer.setForceRasterRender #AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'setForceRasterRender'
```

and:

```
renderer = QgsFeatureRenderer() 
renderer.setForceRasterRender #AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'setForceRasterRender'
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

Both generate AttributeErrors. What is the correct way to set it?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. As simple as:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.renderer().setForceRasterRender(True)
```